# Specify always_inline for functions by Compiler

Tags: c++, real-time, inline, vxworks, workbench

I am building a RT CPP program that make use of other CPP code.
I cannot change the reused code!

I need to force the compiler to inline couple of methods.

My Problem is obviously, I cannot add `always_inline` to the code and be happy.

I am working with   `Windriver WorkBench 3.3` for `VxWorks 6.9`

**Note**: I Can change the Environment as i like.

Any ideas?

***Edit (explain the bigger picture):***

- the library is a Clear-Case Project
- the code is a library used by many projects (including my project)
- each project use different set of functions
- in my project we use about 20 functions a lot and want to inline them to gain needed performance

currently, we "HiJack" the files in order to inline the functions,
but this is no good because we are missing the chance to merge changes from the lib repository.

i thought we could use an environment to specify the inline decisions of the compiler, and avoid the "Hijack" state, be able to merge changes in the library, Etc.

**Note**: different projects will want to inline different functions.

Comment: Why do they have to bee inlined?

Comment: Why cant you change the reused code, and why do they have to be inlined?

Comment: the code is a library used by many projects,  we use several (20) functions a lot, and want them inline to gain needed performance.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hijacking the file, why not branch it, and add the inline directives to your version? That way, you can just periodically rebaseline against the latest version, and merge in the latest library.

Alteratively, extract the changes as a patch, and apply the patch as part of the build process. That way at least you arent having to edit it by hand.

or, make the always_inline conditional, so that you can turn it on at compile time. That way, other users wont be affected, which should allow you to make the changes in the library, where they belong

I am not aware of any option in the dev environment to force it to, although you might want to tweak -finline-limit, and probably turn off optimise-for-space.

**BUT** have you confirmed the overhead of the function call is actually making a difference?

Comment: hi, thanks for an elaborate respones. the always_inline gives 4-5% boost in performance which in this project needed.
making a conditional always_inline flag is problematic because there are many project with different inlining preferences.
patch, is reasonable.. and i will consider that.

Comment: I guess you could group the functions into areas that would typically be inlined together, and have a set of conditionals, but I see the point, it does become more difficult to manage. I would go with branching the library, rather than patch, but either should work.